# Check if user enters data on one line?

Tags: c

What is the most easiest way to check if user inputs multiple data on one line with commas separating them.
This is what I have tried, but the program say good even if I enter numbers on two different lines.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {

        float num1, num2;

        printf("Enter first and second numbers: ");
        if (scanf("%f,%f", &num1, &num2) ) {

                printf("Good \n");
        }
        else {
                printf("Bad \n");
        }
}
```

Easiest way because I am new to C programming.

Comment: Please read [`scanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)'s documentation, you wouldn't be surprised of that behavior at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) to read exactly one line, or [`getchar()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getchar.3.html) if you don't want to limit the length of the given line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char line[1000];

    /* Read exactly one line of input or sizeof(line) - 1 characters */
    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == NULL)
        return -1; /* unexpected error */
    if (strchr(line, ',') == NULL)
        return -1; /* there are no `,' in the input */
    /* Process the input which apparently is comma separated data */
    return 0;
}
```